# Erase TextBlock in DataGrid column if binding gives empty string

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a custom Column:

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Name">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                            <TextBlock Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding PrivateMessage}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I would like to have the TextBlock {Binding PrivateMessage} disappear if it is given an empty string "" such that the DisplayName is centered in the middle and not ontop of it.

Is this possible in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="message" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding PrivateMessage}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PrivateMessage}" Value="{x:Static system:String.Empty}">
            <Setter TargetName="message" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Perfect, had to remove: "{x:Static system:String.Empty}" and put ""

Comment: Any type prepended with a xxx: in XAML is from a non-XAML default namespace and is using an xmlns defined at the top of the file, in this case xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib".